# ODBC Connection - Unable to access the data

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rodbc, rmysql

I usually work with flat files but this time I'm trying to connect to a relational database but with no success. First time for me, I therefore apologize in advance if the question is silly.

Here are the details of the ODBC connection
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZTUE.png)

And here is the code I am using to try to connect

```
install.packages("RMySQL")
library(DBI)
dbConnect(RmySQL::MySQL(),dbname="nicer_med", host="WRGTNICER1", port=3306, user="root", password="xxxxx")
```

and the error message I get

```
> dbConnect(RmySQL::MySQL(),dbname="nicer_med", host="WRGTNICER1", port=3306, user="root", password="Rgt_9098")
Error in (function (cond)  : 
  erreur d'ï¿½valuation de l'argument 'drv' lors de la sï¿½lection d'une mï¿½thode pour la fonction 'dbConnect' : aucun package nommé ‘RmySQL’ n'est trouvé
```

I have tried another strategy using another package

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)
mycon<-odbcConnect("nicer_64")
```

Here the connection seems to work as I am able to describe the tables:

```
sqlTables(mycon)
sqlColumns(mycon,"a_patient")
```

Both are working but my queries actually don't:

```
> sqlQuery(mycon,paste("SELECT PID,NAME, FIRSTNAME1, SEXE, FROM a_patient;"))
[1] "42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.22-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM a_patient' at line 1"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT PID,NAME, FIRSTNAME1, SEXE, FROM a_patient;'"
```

I have tried several Sql dialects : uppercase, lowercase, with or without ";" and """, nothing is working for me.

I am still trying to find a way to have access to the data...I would be very happy to find some help. Thanks.

Comment: After SEXE is a comma too much remove it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally found the issue. It is related to variables having dates as format. I get this error message: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...)

Comment: Your error *here* has nothing to do with date/timestamp formats, it is that your SQL statement has a syntax/parsing error. If you need further help here (and if this is different from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577073/odbc-sqlquery-and-date-format), then I strongly suggest you [edit] your question, fix the syntax error, and add context to justify what is wrong and how this differs from the other. Thank!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Your are right this is redundant with my other qiestion. I'll delete this one